# insert data from one table into another using a condition mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, sql-insert

hello I have the following problem I have two tables let's say these are table 1 and table 2.
Table 1 has column A, B, C, D
and table 2 has column A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
I need to insert data B, C, D from table 1 in table 2 in columns F, G, H using as Condition that A = A

I can not use

> INSERT INTO table2 (F, G, H) SELECT B, C, D FROM table1;

since the data is out of order so when inserting the data they would be mixed

Is it possible to make a sentence that complies with the request, and if it complies, in what way would it be?

Comment: It seems that you would just re-order the SELECT statement from Table 1 so that it matches the order of the columns in Table 2. Also, be aware of types and proper casting if necessary. There is no restriction, at least without clauses like 'HAVING' and 'GROUP BY' that would stop you from doing so.

Comment: Can you write a SELECT that emulates the desired result? (And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 'Condition that A = A;' - looks more like an update than an insert , and what do you mean data is out of order- please illustrate by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to insert data B, C, D from table 1 in table 2 in columns F, G, H using as Condition that A = A

I think you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.a = t2.a
set t2.f = t1.b, t2.g = t1.c, t2.h = t1.d
```

For each row in `table2`, this searches for a match in `table1` with a match on `a`; when found, it updates columns `f`, `g` and `h` of `table2` with values of column `a`, `b`, `c` of `table1`.

For this to work consistently, `a` should be a unique key in both tables.